# Background image elements on top

Tags: php, html, css, background, fullscreen

I've been assigned the task to create a 404.php error page. I just started learning everything and this task is quite difficult. So far I have successuflly:

- set up github + atom
- clone the repository containing some code
- set up MAMP + Wordpress and got the database working
- trying to organize all the terms and trying to not confuse them

It's only been 4 days since I started from scratch with basically everything.

I managed to get this code into the 404.php:

```php
> <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found).
**/

get_header(); ?>
<div id="bg">
     <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> \img\Free-Chalkboard-Backgrounds.jpg" alt="background">
</div>
<header class="entry-header">
<center>
<h1 class="entry-title">404 - Not found</h1>
</center>
</header>

<article id="post-0" class="post error404 no-results not-found">
<div class="entry-content">
<p><big>404 - Die Seite konnte nicht gefunden werden.</big></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
          <!--   <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $logoUrl; ?>" alt="Logo - <?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>">  -->
          <center><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> \img\internet-error-404-file-not-found.jpg" alt="404 not-found"  />
          </center>
        </div>
<!-- .entry-content -->
    </article>
<!-- #post-0 -->
<footer>


   <ul class="list-inline Impressum">
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/seitenbaum/impressum/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>Impressum</a> </li>
       <li> |
       </li>
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/institutionen/hochschulkommunikation/ohm-shop/agb/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>AGB</a> </li>
       <li> |
       </li>
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/institutionen/language-center/ueber-uns/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>Über uns</a> </li>
   </ul>


</footer>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is the css:

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: -64%;
  left: -55%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 55%;
  min-height: 55%;
}
```

It looks like this on the localhost-page:

[preview of 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhdIg.jpg)

How can I make the other elements be on top of the background? I read several answers but I'm so confused right now that I need a specific hint for my case.
Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: just add this style in your css for background "background-position:top center;"

Comment: as a side note: `<center>` and `<big>` tags are deprecated. you should not use them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, what am I to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if i understand you correctly your background is overlapping right now?
I think the property you are searching for is called the z-index.

you probably need to do something like

```
    #bg{
      z-index: -1;
     }
```

[more info about z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I replaced .bg with #bg because it's got `id="bg"` so I need to call it using #? after I did add that to Mr. HKs code, it seems to have worked.

Comment: Whoops! Thats correct i forgot he used a id bg and not a class bg.. thanks for the edit!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it once ...

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found).
**/

get_header(); ?>
<div id="bg">
     <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> \img\Free-Chalkboard-Backgrounds.jpg" alt="background">
</div>
<header class="entry-header">
<center>
<h1 class="entry-title">404 - Not found</h1>
</center>
</header>

<article id="post-0" class="post error404 no-results not-found">
<div class="entry-content">
<p><big>404 - Die Seite konnte nicht gefunden werden.</big></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
          <!--   <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $logoUrl; ?>" alt="Logo - <?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>">  -->
          <center><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> \img\internet-error-404-file-not-found.jpg" alt="404 not-found"  />
          </center>
        </div>
<!-- .entry-content -->
    </article>
<!-- #post-0 -->
<footer>


   <ul class="list-inline Impressum">
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/seitenbaum/impressum/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>Impressum</a> </li>
       <li> |
       </li>
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/institutionen/hochschulkommunikation/ohm-shop/agb/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>AGB</a> </li>
       <li> |
       </li>
     <li> <a href="https://www.th-nuernberg.de/institutionen/language-center/ueber-uns/page.html" target="blank">
       <alt=>Über uns</a> </li>
   </ul>


</footer>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-img {
  background-position: right 45px bottom;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: -64%;
 background-position: top center;
  left: -55%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 background-position: top center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 55%;
  min-height: 55%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I copy pasted your code but the result didn't change. When I reload the 404 page, I can see the elements pop up really quickly but they disappear at once. It's still the same the background image fills the whole screen and everything else is behind it. I found this question which is similar to mine I guess, but I don't know how or where to insert this code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508355/background-image-and-elements-on-it

Comment: You just need to add style in background div only

Comment: Have you tryed?

Comment: yes, I added the Jesse de Gans' `#bg {
     z-index: -1;
    }` to the style.css and now everything is on top. Now I need to add a button and change the fonts. But that's a huuuuge step for me today, thank you!

Comment: @ChrisChromiumCC I'll help you